# Which node fire event in DevExpress SnapControl Data Explorer Dock Panel

Tags: c#, devexpress, snapcontrol

I'm using DevExpress `SnapControl`, and I've managed to replace the "Add Datasource" context menu in the `Data Explorer Dock Panel` by using a custom `MenuCommandHandler` , because the DevExpress datasource wizard takes forever to load, and we are using `Active Query Builder` for the visual query building.

My problem that I have now is that I'm stuck when I want to "Remove Datasource". I can override the event same way as "Add Datasource", but I don't know which `DataSet` is selected in the `treeview` that needs to be removed.

Any help on how to pick up either the node, or the node text that was right clicked on, will be appreciated.

Because `MenuCommand`'s, `CommandID`'s etc is used, I'm a bit out of my depth. It took me a while to be able to override the Event itself that is fired, but figured it out eventually after a couple of hours.

This is my implementation

```
public DevExReportSnapDesignerForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MenuCommandHandler menuCommandHandler = new CustomMenuCommandHandler(report);
    menuCommandHandler.RegisterMenuCommands();
    report.RemoveService(typeof(MenuCommandHandler));
    report.AddService(typeof(MenuCommandHandler), menuCommandHandler);
}

public class CustomMenuCommandHandler : MenuCommandHandler
{
    SnapControl snapControl;

    public CustomMenuCommandHandler(SnapControl snap)
        : base(snap)
    {
        snapControl = snap;
    }


    public override void UpdateCommandStatus()
    {
        base.UpdateCommandStatus();
        DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.CommandSetItem AddDS = null;
        DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.CommandSetItem RemoveDS = null;
        foreach (DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.CommandSetItem item in commands)
        {
            if (item.CommandID == DataExplorerCommands.AddDataSource)
                AddDS = item;
            if (item.CommandID == DataExplorerCommands.RemoveDataSource)
                RemoveDS = item;
        }
        if (AddDS != null)
            CreateCommandEventHandler(new EventHandler(AddDS_OnClick), AddDS);
        if (RemoveDS != null)
            CreateCommandEventHandler(new EventHandler(RemoveDS_OnClick), RemoveDS);
    }

    public void CreateCommandEventHandler(EventHandler handler, MenuCommand item)
    {
        var mcs = snapControl.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as IMenuCommandService;
        var menuCommandID = new CommandID(item.CommandID.Guid, item.CommandID.ID);
        var MenuItem = new MenuCommand(handler, menuCommandID);
        mcs.RemoveCommand(item);
        mcs.AddCommand(MenuItem);
    }

    public void AddDS_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Execute Add Code
    }

    public void RemoveDS_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove Code
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I've assigned an event handler on the MouseDown event of the `SnapFieldListTreeView` now by adding the following code in the form constructor:

```
private SnapFieldListTreeView tv;
private TreeListNode dsTreeNode;

public DevExReportSnapDesignerForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MenuCommandHandler menuCommandHandler = new CustomMenuCommandHandler(report);
    menuCommandHandler.RegisterMenuCommands();
    report.RemoveService(typeof(MenuCommandHandler));
    report.AddService(typeof(MenuCommandHandler), menuCommandHandler);
    tv = fieldListDockPanel1.Controls[0].Controls[0] as SnapFieldListTreeView;
    tv.MouseClick += Tv_MouseClick;
}

private void Tv_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        dsTreeNode = tv.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

This way I can retrieve the node which was clicked on. If there is a better way, please let me know

Comment: How you are using the custom `MenuCommandHandler`? Can you add the code into your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SnapFieldListTreeView` instance directly in your `RemoveDS_OnClick` event handler. You need just to add the `SnapFieldListTreeView` parameter to your custom `MenuCommandHandler` constructor. Currently selected `DataSet` will be in the `SnapFieldListTreeView.FocusedNode` property.
Here is example:

```
public DevExReportSnapDesignerForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MenuCommandHandler menuCommandHandler = new CustomMenuCommandHandler(
        report,
        fieldListDockPanel1.Controls[0].Controls[0] as SnapFieldListTreeView);
    menuCommandHandler.RegisterMenuCommands();
    report.RemoveService(typeof(MenuCommandHandler));
    report.AddService(typeof(MenuCommandHandler), menuCommandHandler);
}

public class CustomMenuCommandHandler : MenuCommandHandler
{
    SnapControl snapControl;
    private SnapFieldListTreeView treeView;

    public CustomMenuCommandHandler(SnapControl snap, SnapFieldListTreeView tree) : base(snap)
    {
        snapControl = snap;
        treeView = tree;
    }

    //Some stuff for MenuCommandHandler.
    //...

    public void RemoveDS_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var node = treeView.FocusedNode;//<= Here comes the selected DataSet's node.

        MessageBox.Show(node.GetDisplayText(""));

        //Remove Code
    }
}
```